# GroupBy and Select extension method assistance

Tags: c#, linq, extension-methods

I am trying to GroupBy a few fields using the following code:

```
var cars = tmp.Select(a => new { a.Make, a.Model, a.Year });

cars = cars.Distinct()
           .OrderBy(a => a.Make)
           .ThenBy(a => a.Model);

var groupedCars = cars.GroupBy(a => new { a.Make, a.Model })
                      .Select(b => new { b.Make, b.Model, b.Year });
```

Unfortunately, the very last line of code is giving me errors as is does not recognize the three fields.

> 'System.Linq.IGrouping(AnonymousType#1,AnonymousType#2)' does not contain a definition for 'Make' and no extension method 'Make' accepting a first argument of type 'System.Linq.IGrouping(AnonymousType#1,AnonymousType#2)' could be found (are you missing a using directive or an assembly reference?)

It is the same error for all three fields (Make, Model, Year).

Any ideas how to fix this?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Once you've grouped the cars by make and model, each element of the sequence is a group. You can get the key for the group with the `Key` property, so you can find the group's `Make` and `Model`, but `Year` makes no sense... there will be multiple cars in each group, and they could all have different years. You can use the information *within* the group, of course. For example:

```
var groupedCars = cars.GroupBy(a => new { a.Make, a.Model })
                      .Select(g => new { g.Key.Make, g.Key.Model,
                                         MinYear = g.Min(car => car.Year),
                                         MaxYear = g.Max(car => car.Year) });
```

But fundamentally you need to be thinking about the fact that each element of the sequence is a group, not a single car.

Comment: That makes sense; however, in this case, I still get the error above even if I remove the Year from the .Select i.e. .Select(b => new { b.Make, b.Model });

Comment: @Sesame, because they are the property of Key, so do `b.Key.Make` and `b.Key.Model`

Comment: Nevermind, I lied... works fine with ".Select(b => new {b.Key.Make, b.Key.Model });" Thank you for your help!

Comment: @Skeet you have been at Google too long. ;-)  Use the GroupBy overload as demonstrated in my answer to do the `Select` projection of the result.

Comment: @OmegaMan It's not really any more convenient to use that overload instead of a `Select`.  If anything I'd say it's less convenient.

Comment: @Servy Your comment is well taken; but my answer provided is along the lines of my only gold moniker `Unsung Hero`. Simply an alternate way of doing things which may provide a spark to someone in the future. No more no less.

Answer (score 0):

I am not going to argue with Skeet's logic for my answer is similar.

But my suggestion is to remove the `Select` projection which does the result selector that sums up the years. That can be done by using the [GroupBy](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/vstudio/bb534493(v=vs.100).aspx) overload which does the same process.

```
cars.GroupBy (car => new { car.Make, car.Model }, // Key selector for make and model as keys
              vehicle => vehicle,                 // Element selector, we want all items of the original car instance which has the year
              (key, vehicle) => new               // Result selector, we want to sum up the min/max year of vehicle.
                                {
                                    Make  = key.Make,
                                    Model = key.Model,
                                    MinYear = vehicle.Min (car => car.Year),
                                    MaxYear = vehicle.Max (car => car.Year)
                                }
              );
```

Result looks like this:

[image]

on this data:

```
var cars = new List<Car>
{
    new Car() { Make="Dodge", Model="Charger", Year=2007},
    new Car() { Make="BMW",   Model="M6",      Year=2007},
    new Car() { Make="Dodge", Model="Charger", Year=2012},
    new Car() { Make="BMW",   Model="X1",      Year=2013},
    new Car() { Make="BMW",   Model="X1",      Year=2014},
};
```