# EF GroupBy: does not contain a definition for 'BriefTitle' and no extension method 'BriefTitle' accepting a first argument of type

Tags: c#, entity-framework, linq

What is wrong with this query?

```
var model =
    SessionObjectsMSurvey.ContractList
    .Where(y => y.ContractTitle.ToUpper().Contains(upper))
    .GroupBy(g => new 
    {
        g.BriefTitle,
        g.ContractId
    })
    .Select(
        x => new
        {
            label = x.BriefTitle,
            id = x.ContractId.ToString()
        }).Take(20);
```

SessionObjectsMSurvey.ContractList is an IEnumerable collection.

This won't compile, I get;

> Error 13  'System.Linq.IGrouping'
>   does not contain a definition for 'BriefTitle' and no extension method
>   'BriefTitle' accepting a first argument of type
>   'System.Linq.IGrouping'
>   could be found (are you missing a using directive or an assembly
>   reference?)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I think you need to insert `.Key` at two places in your `.Select(...)` call. The result of the `.GroupBy(...)` is a queryable of `IGrouping` and that interface contains a `.Key` property to let you access the key of your group.

```
var model =
    SessionObjectsMSurvey.ContractList
    .Where(y => y.ContractTitle.ToUpper().Contains(upper))
    .GroupBy(g => new 
    {
        g.BriefTitle,
        g.ContractId
    })
    .Select(
        x => new
        {
            label = x.Key.BriefTitle,                 // Here
            id = x.Key.ContractId.ToString()          // And here
        }).Take(20);
```

Comment: Thank you for that. A basic point but I wasn't getting there.

Answer (score 1):

Use Key like this:

```
        label = x.Key.BriefTitle,                 
        id = x.Key.ContractId.ToString()
```

See [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22695334/groupby-and-select-extension-method-assistance) link.