# MVC link to sql group by and compare

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, linq, group-by

Thanks to some help earlier on, got the following linq to sql working:

```
decimal? foodCount =
    dbContext.fad_userFoods
    .Where(uf => uf.dateAdded == thisDate && uf.userID == thisGuid)
    .Select(uf => uf.quantityAmount)
    .DefaultIfEmpty().Sum();
```

I would then check to see if foodCount was over a certain number and format the output accordingly.

But I've realised this was a little simplistic. Users could enter the same food multiple times on a day, e.g. an apple for breakfast then an apple for an afternoon snack.

Googling it I've come across including GroupBy. In this case GroupBy foodid. But I'm having trouble getting it to work. (I come from a webforms background where I'd set up a Stored Procedure to do this so MVC and linq to sql are new to me!)

So my expression now reads thus:

```
decimal? foodCount = 
    dbContext.fad_userFoods
    .Where(uf => uf.dateAdded == thisDate && uf.userID == thisGuid)
    .GroupBy(uf=>uf.foodID).Select(uf => uf.quantityAmount)
    .DefaultIfEmpty().Sum();
```

But I'm getting a Visual Studio message which is telling me that "'IGrouping' does not contain a definition for 'quantityAmount' and no extension method 'quantityAmount' accepting a first argument of type 'IGrouping' could be found (are you missing a using directive or an assembly reference?)

quantityAmount was accepted without the GroupBy clause so why is it complaining about it now?

This is my final shot of the day before I switch off so apologise for not getting back to you straight away. But thanks to all who take the time to help.

Comment: Can you explain what is the problem of the original query and what do you want to achieve with the second one?

Comment: have you tried something like this? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/33362478/ef-groupby-does-not-contain-a-definition-for-brieftitle-and-no-extension-meth

Comment: It is complaining because your records are now in groups.  If you think of a rolodex, where you have "groups" for each first letter, you can't ask for example, what is the phone number of the person in tab "A".  Tab "A" doesn't have a person, it has a group of them.  Which one in that group did you want the phone number for.  Hope that helps.  I would highly suggest that you look into a free(ish) program [LINQPad](https://www.linqpad.net/) which can help you visualize the results you get from your queries as you build them up.

Comment: You can't insert in the query chain a LINQ operator that changes the **structure** of the result and expect the rest of the query to continue working w/o modification

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`GroupBy` returns a mapped object of keys and a list of values that match those keys. You didn't really explain your exact needs, but from the return value you are looking for, I don't think `GroupBy` is really helping you, as you still are looking for a sum of all quantities of ALL food for a day. The original statement is still true no matter if the food type changes or not.

If you do this:

```
dbContext.fad_userFoods
  .Where(uf => uf.dateAdded == thisDate && uf.userID == thisGuid)
  .GroupBy(uf => uf.foodID, uf => uf.quantityAmount)
  .ToDictionary(g => g.Key, g => g.Sum())
```

Then you can get these results (note that foodId may actually be a number, not a name):

```
FoodId    Count
Apple     3
Orange    12
Sandwich  2
```

Comment: This gives me exactly what I need. A sum of the food items for any person on any given day. Thanks for your help and to the others who took the time to respond.